# Removing dups from doubly linked list in C++

Tags: c++

while dry run on page it works fine, but when I tried to run that code in C++, it will throw exception "Access Violation Reading locaiton", Someone please help me...

```
void dll::compress(){
    Node *temp1, *temp2, *dup;
    temp1 = head;

    while (temp1 && temp1->next)
    {
        temp2 = temp1->next;

        while (temp2)
        {
            if (temp1->data == temp2->data)
            {
                dup = temp2;
                if (temp2->next != NULL){
                    temp2 = temp2->next;
                    temp2->prev = temp1;
                    temp1->next = temp2;
                    delete dup;
                }
                else {
                    temp1->next = NULL;
                    delete temp2;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                temp2 = temp2->next;
            }
        }
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: post the gdb core dump analysis here.

Comment: if you are on linux, for generating coredump, execute these commands in shell:  ulimit -c  , run the exe , if it crashes, a core file gets generated , then, execute command: gdb -c "core file name" exe.name

Comment: I am on Windows and using Visual Studio (C++) @basav

Comment: delete temp2;temp2=NULL; try this

Comment: Thanks it worked! @basav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `delete temp2;` you keep looping, but `temp2` is both non-`NULL` and invalid.

You need to either set it to `NULL` or `break` out of the loop.

Comment: Should I break the loop after deleting `temp2` ?

Comment: setting temp2=NULL; after delete should work i guess.